# Динамическая смена обложки через VkNet

Tags: c#, .net, vknet

Имеется два вопроса:
1) В данной библиотеке не смог найти методы для работы с обложкой вк. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим и имеет ли решение?
2) Плюс ещё: если я напишу программу меняющую картинку на обложке, откуда мне её можно запускать, чтобы смена происходила автоматически по воскресеньям например (не для коммерческих целей, просто в группе факультета надо менять обложку с надписью числитель, знаменатель :D)

P.S. имею ввиду большую обложку, а не аватарку группы (для примера приведу обложку сообщества NBA)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы про аватар группы, то читайте [документацию vk](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=3.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0). Сама библиотека должна обладать всеми методами.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я имею ввиду большую обложку

Comment: Ну тогда [Документация](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=11.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8%2B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) и методы [photos.getOwnerCoverPhotoUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getOwnerCoverPhotoUploadServer) и [photos.saveOwnerCoverPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveOwnerCoverPhoto). В библиотеке судя по [GitHub](https://github.com/vknet/vk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=saveOwnerCoverPhoto&type=) методы есть в коде, так что дерзайте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое за подсказку. А на вторую часть вопроса не сможете ответить?

Comment: А это уже зависит от многих факторов. К примеру, денег... Не кто за просто так не будет размещать у себя проекты. Если хотите нормально, найдите хостинг с windows. Еще как вариант (кстати бесплатный вроде как) - это сделать все на asp.net или asp.net core и разместить это на Azure, они раньше вроде небольшие проекты бесплатно держали. Ну а так сделайте либо по cron вызов, либо еще какими способами ваш скрипт.